# Cypress - Assertion gets evaluated before due time (possible promise chaining mistake)

Tags: typescript, cypress

I am developing a simple test case in Cypress/TypeScript which edits the selected value of a dropdown.

I am chaining promises and using Page Object. The issues are, so far, 2:

1. An assertion that is meant to be executed/evaluated at the very last, gets executed before.
2. The point one leads to a failed assertion but the test passes anyway (which I don't understand).

screenshot: cl.ly/e4cb6837377c

spec

```
    it.only('C180: Change Tracking type: Important tasks => Time measurement', function () {
        const timeMeasurement = 'Time measurement'
        billing.currentTrackingType().then((trackingType) => {
            if(trackingType == timeMeasurement)
                this.skip()
            billing.changeTrackingType(1).then(() => {
                billing.currentTrackingType().then(($trackingType) => {
                    expect($trackingType).to.contain(timeMeasurement)
                })
            })
        })
    })
```

Page object:

```
    currentTrackingType() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const timer = Cypress.$(this.elements.timer)
            resolve(timer.length? 'Time measurement':'Important tasks')
        })
    }

    changeTrackingType(index: any){
        const settingsChanged = 'Timesheet settings has been changed'
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            cy.get(this.elements.trackingType).select(index.toString())
            cy.get(this.elements.save).eq(3).click()
                resolve()
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cypress commands run asynchronously - they are enqueued and executed in order.

Take this example from your code:

```js
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            cy.get(this.elements.trackingType).select(index.toString())
            cy.get(this.elements.save).eq(3).click()
                resolve()
        })
```

This promise will resolve immediately - `cy.get().select().get().eq().click()` will be synchronously enqueued, then `resolve()` will immediately get called.

If you REALLY want to use the Promise pattern, you would need to do it like this:

```js
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            cy.get(this.elements.trackingType).select(index.toString())
            cy.get(this.elements.save).eq(3).click()
            .then(resolve)
        })
```

`resolve` will be called once the `click` completes.

---

I would recommend restructuring your code to take advantage of how Cypress works, instead of trying to "promisify" it.

Spec:

```js
    it.only('C180: Change Tracking type: Important tasks => Time measurement', function () {
        const timeMeasurement = 'Time measurement'
        const trackingType = billing.currentTrackingType()
        if(trackingType == timeMeasurement)
            this.skip()
        billing.changeTrackingType(1)
        const newTrackingType = billing.currentTrackingType()
        expect(newTrackingType).to.contain(timeMeasurement)
    })
```

"Page object":

```js
    currentTrackingType() {
        // this might not work like you expect - try
        // cy.get(this.elements.timer).then($el => { ... }) instead
        const timer = Cypress.$(this.elements.timer)
        return timer.length ? 'Time measurement':'Important tasks'
    }

    changeTrackingType(index: any){
        const settingsChanged = 'Timesheet settings has been changed'
        cy.get(this.elements.trackingType).select(index.toString())
        cy.get(this.elements.save).eq(3).click()
    }
```